# Cross Site Scripting :Dom

Tags: javascript, security, xss, fortify

While running the HP Fortify analyser, I got a particular piece of code to be vulnerable and has been marked a critical issue.

```
var f = document.createElement("form"),
baseURL = (window.location.origin)+ (window.location.pathname);

f.setAttribute("action",baseUrl);
```

Now this particular line is throwing issue like it is sending unvalidated data to web browser which can result in browser executing malicious code.

Can any one help me solve this issue?

Comment: "Can any one help me in solving this issue" — No. If there is a vulnerability, it will be in how the server processes the URL when the form is submitted. That is where the defence needs to be.

Comment: @Quentin I mean how can I the resolve fortify issue marked as critical? Do I need to use any encoder?

Comment: There is nothing dangerous or risky about that code unless the server side code is very badly written. So you check the server side code and then ignore the testing tool when it is overly paranoid.

Comment: I am getting the same problem, mine says mybaseUrl is unvalidated even through I have it validated